# Where to find a processed list of all valid CSS color strings?

Tags: css, list, colors

I need a list of all CSS color strings like "green", "blue", "red" etc. (there should be more than 140) which is allready processed so I could easily implement it in a database with not too much effort.

Does anybody have a source?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I should have been more specific. With processed I mean something like a textfile which contains one color string per line. Don't need the hex values.

Comment: What do you mean by "processed"? The [CSS3 Color module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color) lists all the color keywords if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: With processed I mean something like a textfile which contains one color string per line. Don't need the hex values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go i uploaded the list for you : [link](http://textuploader.com/r2s8)

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have been more specific. With processed I mean something like a textfile which contains one color string per line. Don't need the hex values